# Absolute positioned div at the top of overflow scroll-y div hiding

Tags: css

I have a absolutely positioned div at the top of a scrolling div. The content of the absolutely positioned div is partially hidden, due to the scroll.

Is there away around this? z-index doesn't work with it, and padding-top can't be used.

This image shows the top of the container, the scroll section, and padding that was added to show the content box that's being hidden.

[image]

```
.hidden-container{
position: absolute;
display: block;
top: -111px;
left: 182px;
z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: Please prove your code. Try adding `padding-top` to the `<div />`.

Comment: There's a filtering bar at the top, padding would normally solve this but it would push the rest of the content down.